# PHP output sorting

Tags: php

Below is a part of my PHP code where it echos the result in an array format. I'm trying to make it so it posts the result in a table. What should I do?

```
//-display the result of the array
  echo "<ul>\n";
  echo "<li>" . "<a  href=\"search_search.php?id=$ID\">"   .
          $FirstName . " " . $LastName . " " . $Email .  "</a></li>\n";
  echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Use table html or css ?

Comment: Doesn't look like an array to me, you need to do a foreach on the result array

Comment: \n as used above will add a line break to the source code output, as opposed to a <br/> tag which will add a line break to the resulting visual display. you really want to use <br/> as you code is used for  a visual output/

Comment: @Adam how can I do that is there a tutorial on the web?

Comment: @user3463859 have a look here: http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/6.html

Comment: the problem is I don't know where to fit this line in any of the formats suggested : "<a  href=\"search_search.php?id=$ID\">"

Answer (score 0):

Do something like for html table-

```
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: where should I link to this page then? echo "<li>" . "<a  href=\"search_search.php?id=$ID\">"

Answer (score -1):

Go back to basics, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Look at *Display the Result in an HTML Table*.

Comment: Please _don’t_ recommend w3schools as a learning resource – because: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: I checked this link before but I don't know how to incorporate this part to it? "<a  href=\"search_search.php?id=$ID\">"